# Create a installer for web application in c# using Wix

Tags: c#, wix, installation, web-deployment, wix3.8

I have installed the Wix from [Wix.codeplex](https://wix.codeplex.com/) and i created a setup file successfully for windows application and its works well.

Now i have a web app and i want to create a installer for my web app (service installer),i tried with creating a setup file by building the Wix-setup project after adding the reference of the web app projects/Files in the Wix project,but it didn't workout, is there any good resource i can follow or any help greatly appreciate!

Comment: Did you try a web search for "wix tutorial" or something similar? Was there anything wrong with the results?

Comment: I was stuck at harvesting the publish folder , but finally got a working installer steps i followed added below and thanks Twon-ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy steps that creates a installer for you application

1. create web application.
2. build and publish.
3. harvest the publish folder and thats creates me a .wxs file.
4. create a setup project in the same solution of my web app.
5. add .wxs from step3 to the setup project.
6. build the setup project it create a .msi(installer) and .wixpdb file.